# Cannot get certain COMs to register using Visual Studio Deployment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, installation, registration

I'm deploying an MSI that includes several C++ COMs.  We're adapting it to work on Windows 7/Server 2008, and for some reason self registering the COMs no longer works.  As a result, I've changed them all to be COMRelativePath.

This seemed to have worked, but 3 of the components are, mysteriously, not registering.  During the build of the installer I see this message for those that are not registering:

WARNING: Unable to create registration information for file named 'ComponentThatWontRegister.dll'

Having done extensive research and tried every work-around, I cannot get past this.  I've tried setting both RegCap.exe and devenv to run in various compatibility modes and elevated to administrative privelages.  I've tried Visual Studio 2010, same issue.

The odd thing is that most of the COMs register just fine and they are ALL set the same way; it's only a very few that are having this issue.  I've gone through the COMs item by item and I can't find anything that would make one fail and another succeed.  Also, on the same system if I register the com using regsvr32 it works so long as I run the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Try running the msi from the command prompt (as admin) and let me know what happens. There's MSI problems conflicting with UAC in windows 7 and it could be causing your problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here; the problem is that the COM registration info isn't even in the MSI after it's built due to the error shown.  Or are you saying to do this after switching it to COMSelfReg?

Comment: After switching it to COMSelfReg.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h793hc1y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) indicates that the error can occur if two or more components in the msi have the same progid. Could this be the cause?

Comment: No.  This installer has been working for several years now using the same same components.  It only became an issue when these Windows 7 and Server 2008 machines stopped allowing self registration, which also would have caused a problem if I had duplicate program IDs (not immediately but functionally).

Answer (score 0):

If these are ATL controls, some may link with ATL.DLL, some not. Depending on the deployment target versus build machine, you may get an ATL.DLL that is UAC aware whilst the static regsitrar using ones are not, when compiled against an older platform SDK.

Compare the linker options of the components that fail to the ones that succeed.